# NameError: name 'find_stack_level' is not defined when trying to get an xlsx file from a website

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I was trying to import a xlsx file from a website using the

```
requests
```

packaged and it returned me an strange error. The code and the error below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
import requests as rq

url = "http://pdet.mte.gov.br/images/Novo_CAGED/Jan2022/3-tabelas.xlsx"
data = rq.get(url).content
caged = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(data))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Perfil\Desktop\UFV\trabalho_econometria.py", line 9, in <module>
    caged = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(data))

  File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 344, in read_excel
    data = io.parse(

  File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1170, in parse
    return self._reader.parse(

  File "C:\Users\Windows\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 504, in parse
    if header is not None and is_list_like(header):

NameError: name 'find_stack_level' is not defined
```

Was trying to read an xlsx sheet from a website and got a strange error.

Comment: Please update the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: It appears from the web that this may be a version issue.  You might try `pip install --upgrade pandas`.